# My Regulator will not fit my CO2 tank

Tags: carbonation, co2

I live in South Korea and had to buy a 20lbs CO2 becuase they would not service my american 5lbs tank. Unfortunately, my current CO2 regulator will not fit on the korean tank. I assume it is becuase of a metric-standard conversion issue.

The regulator I own is the following: [http://www.amazon.com/Commercial-Grade-Double-Gauge-Regulator/dp/B0026K6OY8/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1386293625&sr=1-2-fkmr0&keywords=metric+co2+regulator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026K6OY8)

Do I need to just bite the bullet and buy a korean (metric) regulator or is there an adapter that I could buy? Also, does anybody know where I could purchase either of these items? Thanks.

-Spasm

Comment: Where exactly did you purchase your 20lb tank in Korea?? Been looking for one for a while now. Mark

Answer (score 2):

Getting metric to imperial is hard to find at the best of times.

Finding one for a CO2 connector is going to be very unlikely.
As gas connections are normally a speciality thread (often the opposite direction thread, turn clockwise to undo. This is so idiots don't try to screw a bolt in or something)

Do a quick google to find the thread specs, and then google for a converter.

It will probably be easer (and possibly cheaper actually) if you just buy a new regulator.

You wont have to deal with the extra thread seals etc that way as well